# Transfer event between two scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have table view and scroll view. Table view is on scroll view. Now I want to drag scroll view and if scroll view dragged to some point, scroll view should stop drag and table view start to scroll within single drag (touch) event. I tried it with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and also tried with implementation of `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`.

But not getting success.

This is implementation [Please go through image. table view scrolling and depend on that above view moved to top. now i want table view scroll to stop and move table view and topView to top and when topView invisible tableview should scroll withn that single drag event]

Up Scrolling Table View:

[image]

Down Scrolling Table View:

[image]

Comment: Its typically a bad idea to put a scrollview (tableview in this case) inside another scrollview. I would have a look into using tableview header / footer views and / or tableview section header / footers. If your UI doesn't fit into something like that, I would consider re-thinking the UI

Comment: Correct. I also tried with table header view but requirement is like if table view scrolled at last and we drag it to bottom top view should visible with that drag effect. If we use header view it will gone to top and not able to get it visible if drag table down

Comment: Use Auto layout - It can be easy with that

Comment: it's already in Auto layout. Are you understand what is question?